# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. while i try for Unity Dependency

Tags: c#

Here i wana to add Unit dependency soi had take 3-Projects as Univers(MVC),Moon(ClassLib),Service(ClassLib)its Responsible for Unit Dependecy

Moon
Here i had Take 1-Interface  2-ClassFile

```
 public interface IMoon
    {
        string Gotomoon();
    }
  public class MoonImp : IMoon
    {
        public string Gotomoon()
        {
           return"Hello moon how r u.....";
        }
    }
```

**Service.cs**

Here i had Take 1-IService 2-Service  3-ContainerBootstrap.cs

```
public interface IService
    {
        string Gotomoon();
    }
 public class ServiceImp : IService
    {
        private IMoon Moon;


        public ServiceImp(IMoon moons)
        {
            this.Moon = moons; 
        }
        public string Gotomoon()
        {
            return Moon.Gotomoon();
        }
```

ContainerBootstrap.cs

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container
                     .RegisterType<IMoon, MoonImp>()
                     .RegisterType<IService, ServiceImp>();

        }
```

Now i Come to Universe  its my MVC File
Here i had Take  UnityDependencyResolver .cs file and wrote some code

```
 public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;


        public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (!this.container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
               return this.container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (!this.container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
            else
                return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
 **UnityConfig.cs**
```

Now i had taken a classfile as UnityConfig.cs in App_Start

```
public class UnityConfig
    {
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(()=> 
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterType(container);
            return container;
        });


        public static IUnityContainer Getconfiguration()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }

        public static void RegisterType(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            ContainerBootstrap.RegisterTypes(container);
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**
Now I register that File in Global as

```
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Getconfiguration()));
```

Now I implement in HomeController.cs

```
private  IService serviced;
        public HomeController(IService service)
        {
            this.serviced = service;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.msg = serviced.Gotomoon();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: why minus Here i'm Gettin Error as No Parameterised found

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is.. sounds like you are missing an empty constructor in one of your classes..

Comment: but i think  did Every thing fine if u did any mistake could u plz Suggest me where i'm Doing Mistake...

Comment: Surely you can at least point to the line where the error is?  Why would this not seem important?

Comment: Here i completely Hang where Exeactly error Hits and Why?Here i Completely Ner For this Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this Problem already And also i'm with Mr.j...Comment....Here you did not Register your HomeCOntroller
Please Add this

```
 public static void RegisterType(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            ContainerBootstrap.RegisterTypes(container);
            container.RegisterType<HomeController>();
        }
```